# Change SQLite to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have a `MySQL` database(`xampp` server) and I've found this code that uses `SQLite` database.

```
Cursor cursor = builder.query(**mDatabaseOpenHelper**.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

On what should I change `mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()` if I want to use this code but with MySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `MySQL`, you cannot use `SQLite`.

Please refer [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/). You have to write `PHP` script in order to perform a data operation and finally use `JSON`.

Comment: I want to use MySQL instead of SQLite but I don't know on what should I change this line of code:                                                                                    mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()

Comment: if you want to get data from MySQL, you cannot just change `mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()`. You need to write a php script .